# Force FloatLayout to be square?

Tags: python, layout, kivy, kivy-language

I have a floatlayout with some widgets inside:

```
    fl = FloatLayout(size=(600,600),
                     pos_hint=({'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5})) 

    pos1 = ImgButton(source='zulgrey.png',
                     size_hint=(0.2,0.2),
                     pos_hint=({'center_x': 0, 'center_y': .43}))

    pos2 = ImgButton(source='zulgrey.png',
                     size_hint=(0.2,0.2),
                     pos_hint=({'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.93}))

    pos3 = ImgButton(source='zulgrey.png',
                     size_hint=(0.2,0.2),
                     pos_hint=({'center_x': 1, 'center_y': .43}))

    pos4 = ImgButton(source='zulgrey.png',
                     size_hint=(0.2,0.2),
                     pos_hint=({'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': .43}))
    fl.add_widget(cove)
    fl.add_widget(pos1)
    fl.add_widget(pos2)
    fl.add_widget(pos3)
    fl.add_widget(pos4)
```

However when I resize the window the positions of the widgets move from where I intended them to be. Is there a way I can force the floatlayout to have a fixed aspect ratio on resize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it like this:

```
FloatLayout:
    size_hint: 1, None
    size: self.width, self.width
```

*size_hint: 1* doesn't have to be one, I just wanted my square to fill the size of the FloatLayout.

Alternatively:

```
FloatLayout:
    size_hint: None, 1
    size: self.height, self.height
```

Answer (score 0):

well, yes, with an indirection and some basic math.

Put the widget into another FloatLayout, and bind this floatlayout's size to a function to update your current floatlayout.

```
def update_size(self, inst, size):
    target_ratio = 16/9.
    width, height = size
    # check which size is the limiting factor
    if width / height > target_ratio:
         # window is "wider" than targeted, so the limitation is the height.
         fl.height = height
         fl.width = height * target_ratio
     else:
         fl.width = width
         fl.height = width / target_ratio
```

you want to disable size_hint on `fl` so the method can effectively set its size, also, you certainly want fl to be centered on its parent layout.

```
fl.size_hint = None, none
fl.pos_hint = {'center': (.5, .5)}
```